# Keep maven repo in github

Tags: git, maven, repo

How to keep Own maven repo in github.

There are some maven repo which I am using, I have to put it in some centralized place. So that everyone can access.

And then I should define in pom.xml.

Suggest how to do that by step by step.

Comment: Start using a repository manager...don't use a version control for that...

Comment: Repository manager means, Can you please give one example.

Answer (score 2):

Try Artifactory, it is a binary repository software that you can use its OSS version for working with Java / Maven artifacts. 
you can download the OSS from [here](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/)

You can also find the complete wiki pages for almost anything you need out of this software [here](http://wiki.jfrog.com)

Also you can find video tutorials for working with Artifactory on Youtube, just search for JFrog.

disclaimer: I work for JFrog the company that created Artifactory

Answer (score 0):

The best is to read the overview on [Maven Project](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html). In general a repository manager handles a repository locally for you (or in your company). So you can turn off the internet connection and can continue to use those artifacts. Examples are Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva....